# Monotonicity of Jaccard and Dice in multilabel datasets

Tags: multilabel-classification, jaccard-coefficient, f1score

I understand that Jaccard and Dice follow a monotonic relation on binary datasets because the two are related as $J = {S \over {(2 - S)}}$, and I guess this would be the case when micro-average is used with multi-label datasets. However, would the two metrics follow a monotonic relation when macro-average is used?